# bootstrap select list item using angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript

I have a Bootstrap i want to drop-down list item. list items contain image and texts. i am using `bootstap drop-down` menu Click drop-down list to update value.

how custom select box using `angular2` ?

```
<ul class="btn-group" dropdown>
  <li>
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" dropdownToggle data-toggle="dropdown" dropdown [(ngModel)]="selectaccountno">
      <div class="accountIcon"><i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <strong>Gift Card Account</strong>
      <div>1242 3545 4654 5675</div>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <div class="accountIcon"><i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <strong>food Card Account</strong>
        <div>1242 3545 4654 5675</div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
      <li>
        <div class="accountIcon"><i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <strong>Fuel Account</strong>
        <div>1242 3545 4654 5675</div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
      <li>
        <div class="accountIcon"><i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <strong>Card Account</strong>
        <div>1242 3535 4654 5675</div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
      <li>
        <div class="accountIcon"><i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <strong>Account</strong>
        <div>1242 3545 4654 5675</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown ?